# I want to write a LaTeX document in Yiddish

Tags: languages

I'm trying to find Yiddish support in LaTeX. There's the Makor2 package, which has an elegant solution, but it depends on Omega and Lambda, which are discontinued. Is there any easy way to write in Yiddish (not Hebrew) using a package contained in the latest TeX Live?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: As the main language or just some words or sentences?

Comment: I want to translate Landau's "Foundations of Analysis" into Yiddish. It's a book that is in the public domain in the original German and in the English translation, written by the first Jewish professor to be dismissed in Nazi Germany under the Nuremberg Laws, betrayed by a former student who joined the SS.

He dedicated the book to his two daughters. I'd love to see a Yiddish version, but I guess I'll have to translate it myself. There is a lot of mathematics in the book, hence LaTeX.

Comment: @JeremyGross  Anyway, my answer includes both options.

Answer (score 11):

Yiddish is supported by `babel`. Support is not complete, but you can fill the gaps easily following the indications printed to the log file.

##### As the main language

Here is a monolingual example with Yiddish as the document language (text from Wikipedia), using `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bidi=basic, yiddish, provide=*]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}{FreeSerif}

\begin{document}

\section{אינטערנעץ}

מער ווי 10,000 ביכער אויף יידיש, אפשר מער ווי העלפט פון אלע ביכער
פארעפנטלעכט אויף יידיש, זענען אצינד אנליין מיט דער ארבעט פון די יידישער
ביכער-צענטער, וואלונטירן און דער אינטערנעץ ארכיוו.

\end{document}
```

[image: Yiddish]

##### As a secondary language

Here is an example of a German document with some Yiddish words or sentences (again `lualatex`, again from Wikipedia):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bidi=basic, ngerman]{babel}
\babelfont[yiddish]{rm}{FreeSerif}

\begin{document}

\section{Aleph und Ajin}

Entsprechend schreibt man: \foreignlanguage{yiddish}{אַלט} (alt ‚alt‘),
\foreignlanguage{yiddish}{אָװנט} (ownt ‚Abend‘),
\foreignlanguage{yiddish}{אײַז} (ajs ‚Eis‘).

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good answer. I’d add, if using a language with long words and no hyphenation patterns, you might want to `\usepackage{microtype}` and `\emergencystretch=3em` to make the line-paragraphs break down less often.

Comment: @Davislor There is a justification mode for this purpose, namely, `justification=unhyphenated`, which activates a line breaking mode that allows spaces to be stretched to arbitrary amounts (and it’s locale dependent). Although for European standards the result may look odd, in some writing systems this has been the customary (although not always the desired) practice. There are currently 4 h&j modes (besides the default one): `unhyphenated`, `kashida` (Arabic, there will be some improvements in the next release), `elongated` (Arabic, very tentative and experimental), and `padding` (Tibetan).

Comment: That is good to know!